# print the function arguments in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, stack, stack-trace

I need to print the value of the arguments of a recursive function function from another function. Below is the funciton.

```
void printarg()
{
  // Print the values of a, b, c, countval (function arguments to func1) 
   int j, nptrs;
   void *buffer[100];
   char **strings;

   nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 100); 

   strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
   if (strings == NULL) {
   perror("backtrace_symbols");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (j = 0; j < nptrs; j++) {
      printf(" a %s\n", strings[j]);
   }

   free(strings);

}
int func1(int a, short b, char c, int count)
{
int x, y, z;  
if (!count) {
  printarg();
  return a; 
}
a = a*3; 
b = b -1 ;
c = c^1;
count--;
return func1(a, b, c, count);
} 

int main()
{
   func1(1,2,5,3);
}
```

I am able to get the stack frame using the bactrace utility. But I am not sure about how to print the values of a, b, c from the stack frame in the function printargs. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: This can't work you define the function `func1` after `main`!

Comment: I did not paste my complete code. I made the change now.

Comment: `backtrace`, I believe, uses assembly to read the value of the `ebp` register (on x86 at any rate) and see the return addresses on the stack.  The variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are also on the stack, most likely (with the cdecl calling convention).  I believe you would also need to use inline assembly and `ebp` to find them.  The C language doesn't _want_ you to read the variables a, b, and c from `printarg`; it's designed to stop you doing that unless you pass them as arguments or declare them global.

Answer (score 0):

**Abandon hope all ye who enter here!**

Below are two ways to get the information you want.  Neither is portable, and I cannot guarantee they will work on your machine as written (they work on mine).  I have provided examples in which `main` calls `foo`, which is recursive and calls `bar` when the recursion is done.

Both both rely on the stack being laid out like this (as the CDECL calling convention would dictate):

> ```
> local data in `bar`
> `ebp` of foo on nth call
> return address in `foo` on nth call
> ...
> `ebp` of foo on (n-1)th call
> return address in `foo` on (n-1)th call
> first argument to `foo` on (n-1)th call
> 2nd argument
> 3rd argument
> ...
> ```

If you don't follow this, it would pay you to go and search for "calling convention" and see how function calls work in assembly.

In the example all my arguments are integers, which are 4 bytes.  If you want to use arguments of different types, they *might* take up different amounts of room on the stack and so you will have to alter the code.

The first way uses inline assembly, so it is x86 specific (this is a bad thing).  You don't have to know how much room the local data takes up in `bar`, because you grab `ebp` directly (this is a good thing).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar() {
    int * ebp;
    // inline assembler to get base pointer value (gives a location
    // on the stack where the caller's (foo's) base pointer can be found)
    __asm__("movl %%ebp, %[ebp]" : [ebp] "=r" (ebp));
    // go back to base pointer of caller (final foo)
    ebp = (int *)*ebp;
    // skip over the address of the base pointer of the previous caller
    // and the return address
    ebp += 2;
    // here are the arguments to the call of foo that terminated the 
    // recursion
    printf("a=%d , b=%d, c=%d \n", *ebp, *(ebp+1), *(ebp+2));
}   

void foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a) {
        foo(--a, ++b, c);
    } else {
        bar();
    }
}

int main(int argc, void ** argv) {
    foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Compile with `gcc -g filename.c -o filename`.

The second way uses the address of a local variable, which is on the stack, to work out where the stack is in memory, and then works back to the base pointer of the caller.  It does not use inline assembly, so it could potentially work on platforms other than x86.  But it requires knowledge about how the compiler has put local variables on the stack in `bar`, so it's really *less* portable (I had to look in the assembly file to work out that my `x` variable was 16 bytes higher in the stack than the base pointer).

```
void bar() {
    // The variable we will take the address of
    unsigned int x = 0x999;
    // Get the address of x (it is on the stack, because it is a local variable)
    int *xadd = &x;
    // Get ebp of caller; the magic number is 4 32-bit words or 16 bytes.
    // On my system gcc puts 0x999 at 16 bytes past ebp, 
    // the address of 0x999 at 12 bytes past ebp, 
    // and junk at 4 and 8 bytes past ebp.
    xadd += 0x4;
    xadd = (int *)*xadd; // go back to ebp of caller
    xadd += 2; // jump past ebp of previous caller and return address
    printf("a=%d , b=%d, c=%d \n", *xadd, *(xadd+1), *(xadd+2));
}

// foo and main as above
```

As I have indicated in a comment, the C language *does not want you to do this*.  It is designed to give `a`, `b`, and `c` local scope within `foo`.  I presume you have been asked to do this as some kind of cruel and unusual punishment (though I admit it might help you understand the stack layout).